# Counter example of a given two sets .

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives, supremum-and-infimum

let $f:(a, b) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable map, and define two sets, $A=\left\{f^{\prime}(x): x \in(a, b)\right\}$ and $B=\left\{\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}: x \neq y \in(a, b)\right\}$
I know that $\sup B$ and $\inf A$ are different. I would like to find $\sup B$ and $\inf A$. I am also trying to think about and counterexample to analyse here. Another option would try by contradiction that $\sup B$ and $\inf A$ are different.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? That $\sup B$ and $\inf A$ are the same or different? Or some relation between the two?

Comment: *I know that* $\sup B$ *and* $\inf A$ *are different.* --- For better context it might help to explain why you know this to be true (e.g. give a proof in your question or fully cite a reference).

Answer (score 1):

You don't know that $\sup B \neq \inf A$.  Define $f: (a, b) \to \Bbb R$ to be a constant function.  Then $A=B= \{ 0 \}$.